# Image not displaying correct size

Tags: css, image, image-size

I included some social network icons at the bottom right corner of the footer of my webpage. All the icons are of the same size, 22x23 pixels.

However the first icon is displayed as 16x16 pixels, while the second is displayed in its actual size. When I hover over the first image using the chrome developer window the tooltip reads,

```
16 x 16 pixels (Natural 22 x 23 pixels)

<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MontrealIntClinics" target="_blank"><img src="img/youtube.jpg" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MontrealIntClinics" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
```

Have I dont anything wrong, or is it missing any CSS

Comment: You are setting height and width dimension for the image. See <img src="img/youtube.jpg" width="16" height="16" border="0">

Comment: <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MontrealIntClinics" target="_blank"><img src="img/youtube.jpg" width="22" height="23" border="1"/></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MontrealIntClinics" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.jpg"  width="22" height="23" border="1"/></a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup for the youtube image has width="16" height="16" inline. The twitter image doesn't and so will be defaulting to it's normal size.

Answer (score 1):

i see yo specified explicit size for the first but not for second